# How is BaseCommentNode.render() in django_comments triggerred exactly?

Tags: django-templates, django-comments

According to **[Django official doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/custom-template-tags/#a-quick-overview)**, it reads,

> The template system works in a two-step process: compiling (parsing template texts to `Nodes`) and rendering (render `Nodes` to HTML file).

Let us take **django-contrib-comments** as an example, if I have below line in HTML template file,

```
{% render_comment_form for page %}
```

when and how will the `BaseCommentNode.render()`([source code here](https://github.com/django/django-contrib-comments/blob/f9608a71cefc479f8ea5af23b2f6f2d234024c2a/django_comments/templatetags/comments.py#L70)) or any other Nodes' `render()` be triggered? From the source code, I did not see anywhere explicitly trigger the `render()` function.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found that answer from **[Django Official Document](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/custom-template-tags/#a-quick-overview)**.

> When Django compiles a template, it splits the raw template text into ‘’nodes’’. Each node is an instance of `django.template.Node` and has a `render()` method. A compiled template is a list of `Node` objects. When you call `render()` on a compiled template object, the template calls `render()` on each `Node` in its node list, with the given context. The results are all concatenated together to form the output of the template.